# Can’t use .value=“” in a Sharepoint form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I’m working in a call center, I use Sharepoint pretty much, so I’m trying to create a Chrome extension that can fill the form automatically.
But here is the problem, I tried to use a code like this:

`document.getElementById(“TextFieldabc”).value=“something”;`

After I did that, it did appear on the screen the text I wanted, but as soon as I clicked that input, or save button, it would disappear and said “You can’t leave this blank.”

Can you guys give me some suggestions to go over this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("TextFieldabc").value="something";

function callFunction(){
  console.log(document.getElementById("TextFieldabc").value);
}
```

```html
<input id="TextFieldabc"> <br>
<button onclick="callFunction()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Console log returned the string I wanted, but as soon as I clicked that input or save button, it still went back to the old one tho